# Using $set to grab jquery variable and push it to an vue array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I'm pulling data from a API and using jQuery's getJson method to extract the data I'm then trying to assign the data to a vue array object by utilizing app.$set.

So far I've been able to extract the data and assign it to the vue array but I can only access one thing at a time.

```
<div id="app">

    <div v-once id="movies">
        {{movieCall()}}
    </div>

    <div v-for="(movie,index) of movies" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <!-- <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..."> -->
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-title">{{movie}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 



var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    movies: [

        ],
    },
    methods:
    $.getJSON("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=9d9f46b8451885697e5cf7d1927da80f", function (movie) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            app.$set(app.movies, i, movie.results[i].title);

        }

        for (var x = 0; x < app.movies.length; x++) {
            console.log(app.movies[x])

        }
    })

   },
```

I'm extracting the movie and setting the title to the movie array but I'm wanting to assign it instead to a movie{title} object. This is so when I go through my v-for loop I can refer to the movie object array as movie.title, movie.overview, etc. to print them all. e.g.
In other words, is there a way to do:

```
app.$set(app.movies.title, i, movie.results[i].title);
app.$set(app.movies.overview, i, movie.results[i].description);
etc.
```

and have my movie array set up as:

```
movie[
      {title:}
      {description:}
]
```

and finally loop through like:

```
 <div v-for(movie, index) of movies>
 <div class="titles">
 {{movie.title}}
 </div>
 <div class="descriptions">
 {{movie.description}}
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add data key to hold the data set

```
 <script>
       var app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                movies: [],
            },
        methods:
          $.getJSON("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=9d9f46b8451885697e5cf7d1927da80f", function (movies) {
              for (var x = 0; x < movies.results.length; x++) {
                //console.log("\nTitle"+movies.results[x].title);
                //app.movies.$set(x, movie.results[x].title);
                app.movies.push(movies.results[x].title);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(app.movies)) 
            }
          })
        }); 
    </script>
```

And try with this command

```
app.movies.push(movie.results[i].title);
```

Here is a working example or sample which i created : https://plnkr.co/edit/EnepqQqXzEquJlxqjzn6?p=preview

Ref1: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: Here i have created a sample and it works fine https://plnkr.co/edit/EnepqQqXzEquJlxqjzn6?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `movies` like:

```
<div v-for="(movie, index) of movies">
   ...
   {{movie.title}}
   ...
   {{movie.description}}
```

Then populate it as:

```
app.$set(app.movies, i, {title: movie.results[i].title, description: movie.results[i].description});
```

Or, if `i` is incrementing one by one, the equivalent:

```
app.movies.push({title: movie.results[i].title, overview: movie.results[i].description});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but this exactly what I needed.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs a bit of an upgrade / correction before it's OK, so I prepared a snippet for you that does the same thing (with a mockup JSON response), so you can see that you don't need **app** or **$set** for this.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    movies: []
  },
  methods: {
    movieCall() {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          json.forEach(movie => this.movies.push(movie))
          // or just simply:
          // this.movies = json
        })
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.movieCall()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(movie,index) in movies">
    <div>
      <div>{{index + ". Title: " + movie.title}}</div>
      <div>{{index + ". Body: " + movie.body}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to keep this as close to your code as possible (but CSS classes were taken out).

Basically **Vue** is reactive (**data** property), so if you update the data property **movies** the template should immediately react to that and update the UI. That's the core idea of a JS frontend framework.

Accessing data in object syntax (like **movies.title**, with a dot), is another matter. In your project you set up a **data property - movies**, that's an **array**. An array can hold any type of elements - objects too.

The idea is that you download the objects and then read them (one by one) into the **movies data property**. Or, if you receive an array, then **this.movies = response** (make them equal, assigning the response to the movies array.

Then there's an other thing: **Vue templates** have their lifecycle, and **created()** is a hook, that can be used to execute functions when the template is created. If you want something to run once, you should utilize these lifecycle hooks. (Of course, if your app reloads this template, then it executes the hook many times. To avoid this (downloading something multiple times) you should look into state management, but that's a large topic in itself.)

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I don't see anything wrong with the way I called the API

Comment: The problem is not nevessarily with the way you called the API. The problem is with how you set up the result (data) handling. You’ll not be able to call **movies.title**, if **movies** is an array, for example - **.** (dot) is object syntax, while an array would be **movies[0].title**